# подскажите с циклом

Tags: python

```
string = input('Enter here: ')
while input("Хотите продолжить? [y/n]: ") =='y':
```

Если ответ не Y или N -  переспрашивать, пока не введет Y или N.
 Подскажите куда подставить for или if, при нажатии y - оно повторяет цикл при нажатии n завершает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while True:
    _input = input("Хотите продолжить? [y/n]: ")
    if _input == 'n':
        print("Продолжать не будем !")
        break
    elif _input == 'y':
        print("Продолжайте...")
        break
```

Comment: тоже самое что выше написано, повторяет ввод когда наживаешь 'y', а нужно что бы при написании любого текста переспрашивало пока не введешь 'y' или 'n'

Comment: @RostislavPopov  см. обновление

Comment: все огонь, только в конце break убрал